# Securing kubernetes inter-service -- how is this done?

Tags: kubernetes

I've seen [Kubernetes Securing services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461575/kubernetes-securing-services) but I am asking a more basic question.

How are the services secured? I have a repository layer that should not be available outside of the cluster, but only available to services within the cluster. I can't quite see how I can use kubernetes to handle that or whether it does it itself.

Comment: Use ClusterIP service - it's secure and accessible only within the cluster - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 3):

If you mean network level security by restricting how the service is accessed , then there are many types of kubernetes options that you use for exposing the service , but in your case , you expose it using the **Service** of **Type** **ClusterIP** so that it is only available **inside the cluster**.

> Types of Services There are five types of Services:
>
> ClusterIP (default): Internal clients send requests to a stable
>   internal IP address.
>
> NodePort: Clients send requests to the IP address of a node on one or
>   more nodePort values that are specified by the Service.
>
> LoadBalancer: Clients send requests to the IP address of a network
>   load balancer.
>
> ExternalName: Internal clients use the DNS name of a Service as an
>   alias for an external DNS name.
>
> Headless: You can use a headless service in situations where you want
>   a Pod grouping, but don't need a stable IP address.

Here is a manifest for a Service of type ClusterIP:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-cip-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: metrics
    department: sales
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClusterIP` is not available outside the cluster. If you create the service of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`, then that can be accessed outside the cluster.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types